# Basic Maven installation on Mac OS - blank main class error

Tags: macos, maven-3

This is a very basic but bizarre malfunctioning that is specific to my environment but not being a systems programmer I'm not sure how to debug this.

#### Command

```
wget https://dlcdn.apache.org/maven/maven-3/3.8.5/binaries/apache-maven-3.8.5-bin.zip
unzip apache-maven*zip

JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-12.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home \
    M2_HOME=/Volumes/Apps/apache-maven-3.8.5/ \
    /Volumes/Apps/apache-maven-3.8.5/bin/mvn --help
```

#### Output

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Ignoring option MaxPermSize; support was removed in 8.0
Error: Could not find or load main class '
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: '
```

(there is no actual class name)

#### Incorrect answer

- Anything involving `pom.xml` (I am just verifying the installation)

#### Notes

- Inside an Ubuntu docker container the same thing works fine (with JDK 17)
- I tried deleting the ~/.m2 dir
- I've tried with JDK 8
- `brew install mvn` gives the same problem
- Gradle and Tomcat (my more common tools) work fine
- Usually I use `zsh` but the same issue happens in `/bin/sh` and `/bin/bash`
- same issue with `mvnDebug` and `mvnyjp`
- I used maven for 10+ years without seeing this before, so I'm no rookie
- same issue with `apache-maven-3.2.5-bin.zip`

Answer (score 1):

First only use the environment variable JAVA_HOME do not use M2_HOME (not needed nor helpful). Furthermore use separate lines for exporting the environment variables (see https://maven.apache.org/install.html) ...you have concatenated the lines `JAVA_HOME...`with `\` which means it's only a single line. Do not do that.

Download the zip file if you like (better would be the `tar.gz` variant on MacOS).

the following three commands in a terminal:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-12.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home
export PATH=/Volumes/Apps/apache-maven-3.8.5/bin:$PATH
mvn --version
```

The message you got while starting the JVM: `Ignoring option MaxPermSize; support was removed in 8.0` means you have somewhere in your environment a variable like `JAVA_OPTS` set with some options which are not correct.

Comment: Thanks I'll give that a shot next time I'm working on that project (though I don't think any of these are the issue, I probably already tried half of those things but didn't mention them in the question).

Comment: In must be on your side bevause I'm running Maven also on a MacOS...

Comment: absolutely it's something unusual broken in my environment and my usual battery of debugging techniques is deserting me.